# Importing the data into R from MySQL

Tags: sql, r

I imported the data from MySQL but when I try to view the table, I see something like the screenshot I have attached. Can someone guide me through the corrective measure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is about image processing. The SO R FAQ — https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info — explains how to frame a reproducible example for a question. Having said that, you have not imported data into R from MySQL. It looks like you used `dplyr` and likely saw some preview output in the console, but you neglected to use a `collect()` on the table. You should spend some more time reviewing the `dplyr` and `dplyr` + database manual pages & vignettes.

Comment: What is your question? And please show attempted code and errors/undesired results.

Comment: I added the code in the question along with what the desired result is